# Moderator in Liquid Metal Fast Breeder Reactor (LMFBR)

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I wanted to know that what is the moderator used in a LMFBR. I've seen a few sources and there was no mention of any moderator. The only thing mentioned was that liquid sodium is used as a coolant. So, is it so that there is no moderator required in such type of reactors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that is called a fast (breeder) reactor means that sufficient fissions can be initiated by the capture of high energy (fast) neutrons.
Moderators are used to slow down the neutrons without absorbing them.
In a fast breeder reactor no moderator is required.

A thermal breeder reactor would require a moderator to be present because in such a reactor sufficient fissions would only be initiated by slow (thermal) neutrons.

Answer (score 0):

Fast breeder reactor's do not use moderator material's because, they are "encouraging the development of more fission reactions",  and therefore,  would not desire a moderating material(s) to "slow the Process" down.